# Ajax changing php state with javascript button click

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, button

I am trying to display 9 last uploaded images through AJAX, but also be able to navigate through past uploaded images as well.

```
 <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">
              var x = 0;
             var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            nextButton.onclick = function(){
                  x+=1;
                      };

         document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML =         xmlhttp.responseText;

    };

           xmlhttp.open("GET", "getImage.php?=" + x , true);
           xmlhttp.send();

      </script>

             #getImage.php file
                 <?php 
                  $q = $_REQUEST["q"];
                  $req = intval($q);
                  echo $req;
                  ?>
```

I need $req to update every time the button is pressed but also be 0 when the page is loaded so it does not only display the images when the button pressed but  also when the page has just loaded
Thanks

Comment: The main isssue is the $req is not updating when I click the button

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getImage.php?=" + x , true);
```

is wrong as there is no query parameter q replace it with

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getImage.php?q=" + x , true);
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The value of `q` in not passing to php file. Add query string parameter `q`
Just replace this line:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getImage.php?=" + x , true);
```

with this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getImage.php?q=" + x , true);
```

Comment: I did change it, but it is still  not working.  It also does not work when I change it to:        if(x==0)
        {xmlhttp.open("GET", "getImage.php?q="  , true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
        else
        {nextButton.onclick=function(){
        x+=1;
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getImage.php?q=" + x , true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        };
        }